# If my officers die in a campaign, do they die in single missions?

Tags: door-kickers

One of the loading screens for Door Kickers tells me that

> Your officers don't die permanently in Single Missions, but your tactics still suck.

Which is awesome.  But let's say that I play a campaign (maybe even an Iron Man campaign).  **Let's say that my best dude gets capped in the first mission.  What happens to him in Single Mission mode?**  Does he vanish from my roster entirely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just gave it a try.  Turns out **troopers who die in campaign mode are perma-dead and at the end of the campaign, they're replaced with *rookies*.  Not cool.**

Comment: Can't you restart the mission when this happens?